# How to change the size(width) of p:fileupload in prime faces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a p:fileupload but its size can not be reduced. I checked the primefaces3.1 user manual but could not find an attribute to reduce the size of the component.Because of this my fileUpload componenet cut crosses the panel.Please help.I tried to width= but it did not succeed.Below is the code that i use:

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{editBean.editFileUpload}" width="10px"
                        process="studyPlanEditForm:displayname1"
                        update=":studyPlanEditForm">
                    </p:fileUpload>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the attribute styleClass with your own css class and redefine the width inside the CSS.

Comment: Sorry but if you use a p:fileUpload in simple mode (mode="simple", native input type="file") styleClass attribute doesn't change size. I tried with the size attribute but its not recognized by p:fileUpload. I can re-write p:fileUpload rendered to interpret size attribut but i search a simplier solution... Thanks