# How to re-size the <p:fileUpload ...> button in primefaces?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I added a *fileUpload* button in my JSF and wanted to re-size its width using css but non of the following approaches are working. Not enough the container behaves strange when inspecting the rendered html code with *chrome-developer-tools*.

Screenshot of my JSF:

[image]

The element container size is *1891px* and I don't have an idea where it was set by my css file.

My CSS File:

```
 ul {
      list-style: none;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial;
}

#recordingslist audio {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.btn_style1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

.text_style1 {
    font-size: x-large;
}

.text_style2 {
    font-size: medium;
    width: 20%;
}

.text_style3 {
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #007e50;
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
}

.c_style1 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
}

.ui-widget {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100% ! important;
}

.ui-button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

My JSF code:

```
<h:form id="uploadForm">
   <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
   <p:fileUpload id="uploadBtn1" value="#{fileUploadView.file}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true" style="width: 200px; height: 51px;" />
</h:form>
```

I have also tried to set the style attribute of  and the styleClass attribute according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981560/how-to-change-the-sizewidth-of-pfileupload-in-prime-faces?answertab=votes#tab-top), but still no effect.

Has anyone an idea, what I did wrong.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC you are just awesome! +1